# How to install Zend Framework 1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, zend-framework

How can i install Zend 1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04?

I know that i can install zend by using apt-get install zend-framework but that will install the lastest version right?

So what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps detailed in here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

The steps provided there, from enabling a2enmod and so forth should be version agnostic, the link to the ZF 1.12 file is there as well.